# Algorithm to determine the best team and formation?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

I am looking for suitable algorithms I could use in a sports team management simulator (e.g. hockey or soccer).  Some features of the simulator:

- The team can play with different formations (e.g. soccer's 4-4-2).
- Each player in the team has a numeric rating for how good they are for each position in the formation.
- There is a pool of squad players of varying abilities from which the team can be selected

What algorithms can be used to programmatically and efficiently determine the strongest teams and formations?

Comment: It smells NP-Hard (though I don't have reduction in mind) Would you like heuristical approach?

Comment: Yes please, whatever gets the job done fast!

Comment: If it's as "simple" as putting the highest-rated players in each position of the formation, then a greedy algorithm should perform fairly well. I agree with taking the heuristic approach since there's no need to look at *every* different combination.

Comment: @amit NP-complete, I think. May be related to [Job-Shop Scheduling Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling), not?

Comment: Many thanks guys!  Wonderful answers, I am really glad I asked this question now.  It is very hard for me to pick a winner as I don’t feel qualified!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we model your problem by graph and noticing that the number of different formations is small, the problem is [maximum weighted bipartite matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs), which is solvable by [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), ....

To model the problem with bipartite graphs, put players in one part, and positions to the other part (e.g. in soccer), to form a pool of players and 11 positions for them, connect all players to all positions, and set the corresponding edge weights as a corresponding player rating in the position.

Now all you should do is to find a [maximum (weighted) matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) in this complete bipartite graph. (codes are available in wiki link).

I supposed we have a limited number of formations, for each formation we can find the corresponding matching graph, and its maximum weight matching, finally take maximum value over all possible formations (in all graphs).

Comment: That fits my requirements perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could try a heuristical approach using existing AI tools for optimizations, such as [**Genetic Algorithms**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) or [**Hill Climbing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing).

I'll give more details on hill climbing, since it is my favorite.

**Represent your problem as states graph** `G = (V,E)` such that `V = {all possible states }` and `E = {(u,v) | swapping one player you can move from u to v }`.

Also, let `u:V->R` be a utility function for a formation.

Since we do not want to generate the graph, let `next:V->2^V` be a function such that `next(v) = {all possible formation that you can get by changing one player }`

The idea of hill climbing is to **start from a random formation, and greedily make the best change possible**, when you are stuck - restart the algorithm from a new random formation.

```
1. best<- -INFINITY
2. while there is more time
3. choose a random matching
4. NEXT <- next(s)
5. if max{ u(v) | for each v in NEXT} < u(s): //s is a local maximum
   5.1. if u(s) > best: best <- u(s) //if s is better then the previous result - store it.
   5.2. go to 2. //restart the hill climbing from a different random point.
6. else:
   6.1. s <- max { NEXT }
   6.2. goto 4.
7. return best //when out of time, return the best solution found so far.
```

Note that this variation of hill climbing (hill climbing with random restarts) is an **[any time algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anytime_algorithm)** - meaning it will become better when more time is given, and when infinite time is given - it founds the global maximum.

Answer (score 2):

The simples heuristic that can be applied to your problem is the greedy algorithm, whose explanation can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm.

Another solution is to create two dummy nodes (begin and end) and consider your pool of players as an ordered graph (first comes the goalkeeper, then the right wing defender, and so on). The edges will consist of the players rating for the position under consideration. In this scenarion, you will have a scenario where you can apply the A* algorithm, whose description you will find at [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) (just remember that a maximization problem is only a minimization of the inverse function).

Comment: A* is a pathfinding algorithm, I am not sure what path are you looking for, what is the target node in this case? I am not sure I am following this line of thought, would you care to elaborate? :\

Comment: A* is an heuristic to find the minimum cost path between two nodes. The target would be the dummy node "end" that I told you to create. The multiple paths would be the combinations between all players in each positions. Don't worry about combinatorial explosion, for you would only explore some paths (those that look promising for each iteration of the algorithm).